# Batch - Path with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, startup

Hey everyone who looks to my question,
I have been playing around with files and I try something `"start /D %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\<File>.bat"`

I did this to make a loop that runs the bat file again whens it finished.
When I tested this out it got a error

**"C:\Windows\System32>start /D %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\.bat The system cannot find the file Menu\Programs\Startup\.bat."**

```
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
start /D AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\<File>.bat
```

If you know a way to fix this or a way to improve my bat please tell me!

***Note:
I runned it as admin and
the .bat file is in the Startup folder.***

Comment: Don't use `/d`. See `start /?`.

Comment: What is the name of the Batch file? `<File>.bat` is _not_ a valid file name...

Comment: @Aacini The batch file is called test.bat

Comment: Then, I suggest you to change `<File>.bat` by `test.bat` in your line above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the question is not about the filename but on how a batch file can reference itself or loop.

Therefore:

Either use **%0** notation for the last line instead e.g. `Start ""  "%~f0"` or `"%~f0"`

```
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
Start "" "%~f0"
```

Or put a **label** at the top `:Label` then as the bottom line, `GoTo :Label`.

```
:Label
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
<Here is a command>
GoTo :Label
```

As a side note, you may wish to look at scheduled tasks for running a script at login/startup and continue to do so at regular intervals thereafter.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a space in the path, you need quotes surrounding it, and /D is expecting a folder path for the starting directory. In this case, it's interpreting `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start` as the startup folder and `Menu\Programs\Startup\File.bat` as the file to execute. I'm pretty sure you didn't mean that. You don't need to specify a `/D` switch unless your batch file is referencing an external dependency via a relative path from the folder specified after `/D`.

If you have a batch file in your default Windows Startup folder, this will execute it:

```
start "" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\File.bat"
```

Comment: There are not spaces in the path. Yes, the `/D` switch is followed by the `AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start` folder path that specify the starting folder. In this answer a new cmd.exe window is just opened with the string enclosed in quotes as the _title_ of the window. See: `start /?`

Comment: @Aacini : "There are not spaces in the path" Um - so what's that character between "Start" and "Menu" then?

Comment: @Magoo: The start command may have this usage: `start /D path command`, so the original line is _correctly written_ with two parameters: one for /D switch (the _path_) and another one for the _command_. This answer assumes that the /D switch should be removed; however, it is not clear in this point (_"You probably don't need it though"_) and is confusing in this detail: there is not a space in the path because the _path_ is part of the /D switch! There is a space in the _command_ to execute (the name of the .bat file).

Comment: @Aacini: Point taken; "You probably don't need it" is unclear. It wasn't referring to the Start syntax, it was referring to my assumption that he wouldn't have any dependencies that are referenced with relative paths from the Startup folder. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: That won't work, due to the crazy syntax of the start command.  If the argument is in quotes, it is interpreted as a window title, not a command to run.  You'd have to say `start "my title" "%AppData%\Microsoft..."`

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, I already said so in the last part of my first comment...

Comment: Indeed! I knew this once upon a time but forgot in this case. Edited once again. =)